# Poetry takes ages to update dependencies

Tags: python-poetry

Yesterday I've commanded poetry to add new dependency. I'm still waiting...

```
$ poetry add readability
Using version ^0.3.1 for readability

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (66408.9s)
```

Is there any way to fix that or manually update lock?

Answer (score 1):

First run:

```
poetry cache clear pypi --all
```

Then run:

```
poetry lock
```